# jQuery conflict? or something else?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 sites, which should be identical, however one is loading the calendars whilst the other is not - scroll to bottom of page to see the calendars.

```
http://www.sandybarn.co.uk/prices-and-availability/ - not working

http://217.199.187.64/html-template.com/prices-and-availability/ - WORKING!
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Press F12 and post any errors you receive in the console.

Comment: What exactly are your definitions of "working" and "not working"? Is the problem happening in any particular browser or in all of them?

Comment: this is why jquery should be banned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 219 of `wpdev.bk.js`:

```
jQuery('#calendar_booking'+ bk_type).datepick(
```

`.datepick` doesn't exist when called: that's what's crashing your code.
Possible reason: you're currently calling `.datepick` **before** you're including the plugin. Make sure `wpdev.bk.js` is included **after** the plugin.

Comment: Nope... don't just guess... this is not how [this plugin](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) is used.

Comment: LOL - why would you think that the OP is using that plugin? :P I think you just proved that this answer was shot out without much research...

Comment: the burden of knowing which plugin is in use is not mine. OP should inform us of known data. I don't have and I don't want to do that for him. In absence of data, one could only guess. My answer is clear: "datepick" doesn't exists when called. That's crashing the entire code.

Comment: If you are wanting to post an answer and claim that the OP is using the plugin in the wrong way then you have taken it upon yourself to know which plugin is in use.

Comment: I didn't even claimed he's using the plugin. Let alone "in the wrong way".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Saturnix I imagine you are on to something... I will investigate further.

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome/FF/Safari and check the console next time: it will help you in investigating these issues.